# Unkown database error after downloading mysql dump from remote server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I downloaded remote mysql dump with this

```
mysqldump -u username -p -h remote.site.com DBNAME > backup.sql
```

after that when I try to start server I got an error:

```
`rescue in mysql2_connection': Unknown database 'my_database' (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)
```

Do I need to explicitly move my downloaded dump somewhere or is it enough to be downloaded into home directory?

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: root
password: root
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
 <<: *default
database: my_database

test:
<<: *default
database: my_database_test

production:
<<: *default
database: my_database_37
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the same database that you took a dump of or are you starting a local instance of MySQL

Comment: To same that I took as a dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that you want to import the dumped database into your local environment. First, let's create the database

```
rails db:create # or rake db:create previous rails 5
```

then, import your dump

```
mysql -u username -p dbname < backup.sql
```

Comment: Now I can't even create database, again got an error: Unknown database my_database

Comment: Yes i do, same thing

Comment: You are typing this in your terminal, aren't you?

Comment: Can you try `RAILS_ENV=development rails db:create`?

Comment: Again: rescue in mysql2_connection' Caused by: Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'my_database'

Comment: Let's create it in mysql console! `mysql -u username -p` and then inside mysql console `CREATE DATABASE \`your_database\`;`

Comment: Ok now I'm getting an error that I'm missing some table(that's probably from dump file which I downloaded)

Comment: Do you need to run some migrations? `rails db:migrate`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. I give up, sorry

Comment: thank you for help. In spite of I'm a noob, I found it out.  Just needed to import my dump into root folder of the app as you said:)